# C# ignore WCF contract mismatch for backward compatability?

Tags: c#, wcf

The problem is this:

```
[DataContract]
public class StatusA : StatusBase {}
[DataContract]
public class StatusB : StatusBase {}

[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(StatusA))]
[KnownType(typeof(StatusB))]
public class StatusBase {}
```

If I provide this API to end user - all will be fine, but then, later, I add new status:

```
[DataContract]
public class StatusC : StatusBase {}

[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(StatusA))]
[KnownType(typeof(StatusB))]
[KnownType(typeof(StatusC))]
public class StatusBase {}
```

And then if end-user stumble in this particular instance - he will catch contract mismatch exception, which in this particular case I want to be ignored just like JSON do when deserializing something unknowable (just fills whatever it can). For example, for paging methods like this, it is critical:

```
List<StatusBase> GetStatuses(int offset, int count);
```

So, my options is to wrap it up into **byte[]** and then manually deserialize it (which will bring a lot of partial duplicated classes) or somehow to tell WCF dispatcher to try soft-deserialize this.

What are my options? Can this be done?

Comment: if you want micky-mouse serialization, use json, datacontracts will break for various reasons, because they are a contract...  there isn't really much you can do about it.. this might help though https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/best-practices-data-contract-versioning

Answer (score -1):

How about avoiding the need for selective serialization altogether by loading the Known Types dynamically using this little trick:

```
[KnownType("GetKnownTypes")]
public class StatusBase 
{
        private static Type[] GetKnownTypes()
        {
            var types = new List<Type>();

            //add all your types here using reflection.
            return types.ToArray();
        }
}
```

Comment: And how it negatiate client error about contract mismatch?

Comment: Which contract mismatch? You won't get contract mismatch if you're telling WCF all known types. All you've to do is load all types from a particular location so the new contracts get loaded automatically.  Should I know the reason for down vote?

Comment: "Backward compatability" in title of question and question itself is the reason for downvote. Client don't have type at all (not even close have it, literally, it doesn't exist in client dll) but server do have it and some of clients which updating every day probably have it too, what it means? - contract mismatch, and your code sample won't help here.

Comment: You didn't mention if the clients have no access to your new types. My solution only works if somehow your clients have access to the new types. In your case it is not advisable to create new sub types as you cannot pass them through known types way. Check out 13th point in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/best-practices-data-contract-versioning) guideline by Microsoft. You need to re-design your service versioning mechanism.

Comment: What else I need to mention? How is this exception ever occurs in my examples above if not when user doesn't have access to new type set? If user have new type set - both of my examples will work and no exception will occur. As to proposal of redesign - this is what I asked about, no point to point.